# Is there a vim mode available for `iex`

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

Is there a vim mode available for `iex`? That is, something like `set -o vi` in bash.

Here's my version info: `IEx 1.13.0 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 24)`

I'm running it on `Linux Mint 20.2 Uma`.

Comment: I’m pretty sure there isn’t, because `iex` relies on `erl` which is a rolling implementation of the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `iex` doesn't have vim mode.

However, if you're a vim user, I can recommend you check out [neovim](https://neovim.io). It has a [built-in terminal emulator](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim_terminal_emulator.html) which might solve some of your needs. You could always spin it up and run `iex` within allowing you to more or less navigate the terminal through vim.

Comment: While it would solve editing, line editors vi modes are generally line oriented and one of the common use case for them is to use j and k to quickly go up and down history. Plus in neovim, switching the terminal to buffer mode to line mode is not great. When you need more complex editiing, you can have a shortcut that drop the line in a vim buffer. So it is a bit suboptimal imho.